# when a string exists in registered variable ansible task

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team,

I have two tasks and one is save outout to register variable and next is checking if a strings exists in it. but it calling synatx error. Any hint observed?

Do i need to set fact for this ? if yes how?

```
- name: "Capture DiskCache enablement event via isc pod log"
  command: kubectl logs -n isc-vdiskplugin "{{ item }}" vdisk | grep \"Disk Cache Enabled\"
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: false
  register: isc_pod_log
  with_items: "{{ isc_pod.stdout }}"
  ignore_errors: no
  tags: tag_post_dcro

- name: check variable registered
  debug:
    var: isc_pod_log.stdout

- name: Validate DiskCache is enabled from isc pod logs
  when: "Disk Cache Enabled" in isc_pod_log.stdout
  debug: msg="Disk Cache is Enabled"
  ignore_errors: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: false
  tags: tag_post_dcro
```

output:

```
[Pipeline] }
   ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
     expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'

   The error appears to be in '/ansible-managed/jenkins-slave/slave0/workspace/run_ansible_playbook/k8s/baremetal/roles/diskcache_prerequisites/tasks/main.yml': line 116, column 19, but may
   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

   The offending line appears to be:

   - name: Validate DiskCache is enabled from isc pod logs
     when: "Enabled" in isc_pod_log.stdout
                     ^ here
   This one looks easy to fix. It seems that there is a value started
   with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
   with the same kind of quote. For instance:

       when: "ok" in result.stdout

   Could be written as:

      when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

   Or equivalently:

      when: "'ok' in result.stdout"
```

Quoting entire when

```
when: "'Disk Cache Enabled' in sci_pod_log.stdout"
```

may be my stdout is a list? am getting unable to lookup

```
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check ''Disk Cache Enabled' in sci_pod_log.stdout' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ('Disk Cache Enabled' in sci_pod_log.stdout): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if 'Disk Cache Enabled' in sci_pod_log.stdout %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'AnsibleUndefined' is not iterable\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/dtlu/code/disable-fscache/tasks/main.yml': line 28, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Validate DiskCache is enabled from csi pod logs\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote the entire `when` condition:

```
- name: Validate DiskCache is enabled from isc pod logs
  when: "'Disk Cache Enabled' in item.stdout"
  debug: msg="Disk Cache is Enabled"
  ignore_errors: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: false
  tags: tag_post_dcro
  with_items: "{{ isc_pod_log }}"
```

Comment: may be my isc_pod_log is a list and i need to iterate ? if this is the case, i updated question with output of your answer.

Comment: Yes!  Fixed one problem and ran into another.  I've added the loop over the registered variable, `isc_pod_log`.  So now we use `item.stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

we need to use loop as return is a list

```
- name: Validate DiskCache is enabled from sci pod logs
  when: "'Disk Cache Enabled' in item.stdout"
  debug: msg="Disk Cache is Enabled"
  ignore_errors: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  loop: "{{ sci_pod_log.results }}"
  tags: tag_post_dcro
```